# Convert Black and White Image with Color Palette using Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a black and white image. It contains values ranging from 0 to 30. I want to replace pixel value with an rgb color. For that, I have a list:

```
CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP = [ 
    [  0,   0,   0],   # unlabeled     =   0u
    [128,  64, 128],   # road          =   1u
    [244,  35, 232],   # sidewalk      =   2u
    [ 70,  70,  70],   # building      =   3u
    [102, 102, 156],   # wall          =   4u
    [190, 153, 153],   # fence         =   5u
    [153, 153, 153],   # pole          =   6u
    [250, 170,  30],   # traffic light =   7u
    [220, 220,   0],   # traffic sign  =   8u
    [107, 142,  35],   # vegetation    =   9u
    [152, 251, 152],   # terrain       =  10u
    [ 70, 130, 180],   # sky           =  11u
    [220,  20,  60],   # pedestrian    =  12u
    [255,   0,   0],   # rider         =  13u
    [  0,   0, 142],   # Car           =  14u
    [  0,   0,  70],   # truck         =  15u
    [  0,  60, 100],   # bus           =  16u
    [  0,  80, 100],   # train         =  17u
    [  0,   0, 230],   # motorcycle    =  18u
    [119,  11,  32],   # bicycle       =  19u
    [110, 190, 160],   # static        =  20u
    [170, 120,  50],   # dynamic       =  21u
    [ 55,  90,  80],   # other         =  22u
    [ 45,  60, 150],   # water         =  23u
    [157, 234,  50],   # road line     =  24u
    [ 81,   0,  81],   # ground        =  25u
    [150, 100, 100],   # bridge        =  26u
    [230, 150, 140],   # rail track    =  27u
    [180, 165, 180],   # guard rail    =  28u
    [  0, 254, 254],   # rail raised   =  29u
    [ 90,  40,  40]    # trackbed      =  30u
```

]

How do I accomplish that, without a nested for-loop? I tried using PIL.Image.putpalette, but the colors where wrong. Somehow it only used the first 8 colors, but index 3 got mapped to color 8 (index 7). Below my code:

```
with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    palette = [c for rgb in CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP for c in rgb]
    img = img.convert('P', palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE, colors=len(CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP))
    img.putpalette(palette)
    rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
    rgb_img.show()
    # rgb_img.save(os.path.join(dir, "converted.png"))
```

It does not have to use PIL.Image.putpalette. All other solutions are appreciated also.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's `26u` bridge? Please share your image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert the image to mode 'P' using the ADAPTIVE palette, the palette is generated from the colors in the image, which means that the pixel values in the image might not be mapped to the RGB values you want. Instead, you should convert the image to mode 'P' using the WEB palette and specify a custom palette using the putpalette method. This allows you to control how the pixel values in the image are mapped to RGB values.

```
from PIL import Image

# open the image
with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    # create a palette from the CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP list
    palette = [c for rgb in CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP for c in rgb]
    
    # convert the image to mode 'P' using the WEB palette
    img = img.convert('P', palette=Image.WEB, colors=len(CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP))
    
    # apply the custom palette to the image
    img.putpalette(palette)
    
    # convert the image to mode 'RGB'
    rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
    
    # display the image
    rgb_img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. Then QuestionHaver99 posted his solution. My solution:

```
with Image.open(filepath) as img:
    data = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    palette = np.array(CITYSCAPES_PALETTE_MAP, dtype=np.uint8)
    rgb_data = palette[data]
    rgb_image = Image.fromarray(rgb_data)
    rgb_image.show()
```

My solution took ~0.035 seconds, while QuestionHaver99's solution only took ~0.025 seconds. I went with his solution.